# Crystal Report cross-tab row column cannot grow

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crosstab

I have been using cross tab Crystal report to generate the subtotals to Analyse which company use less cost for purchasing materials. Due to the software constraints provided by Crystal Report, crosstab can only be created in the report header. In the report header, 
we cannot grow the row and columns contents

Now I have to following tables as below

Table A

```
ID CompanyName 
1  Test 
2  Tast
```

Table B

```
Foo Bar ParentID Quantity Rate
A   1   1           21     10
B   2   1           10     222
C   3   1          11      1243 
A   1   2           2      10
B   2   2           20      222
C   3   2          13       1243
```

I would like to create the table as the report :

```
   Foo Bar Rate  Test  Tast  
    A   1    10     21    2
    B   2    222    10    20
    C   3    1243   11    13
Total              42    35
```

In the column section, the company names can be dynamically generated mean while Foo,Bar, and Rate are fixed.

So, my question is
 1. How to set the row objects and  column objects in crossTab so that they can display all contents without overlapping ?

1. How to custom add the fixed columns in the cross tab report ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross tab is used to display row-wise data. Also row to column or column to row display.

please check this links, This is help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493334/Custom-sorting-for-Crystal-Report-Cross-Tab

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166291/Generate-a-report-using-Crystal-Reports-in-Visual

Comment: I don;t want to add the columns directly in the crosstab expert because there are not the grouped attributes. HOw should I start with ?